# Como fazer um cálculo de porcentagem no Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, matemática

Não consigo fazer um `Select` que possa fazer 1 cálculo de IPI no Oracle.

Tabela VS01
Campos:
PD = 001
TP = 100 reais
IPI = 15

```
Select PD,TP,IPI,

       TP * IPI% AS TOTAL <<< aqui que não consigo executar

From VS01
```

PD || TP || IPI || TOTAL

001   100    15     115

Comment: É isso: `select tp, ipi, sum( tp + ipi ) as total from tabela group by tp, ipi` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É pura matemática:

```
Select PD, TP, IPI, TP * (1.00 + IPI / 100) AS TOTAL
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Percent.sql).

Pode ser que queria fazer algum arredondamento.

Comment: Deu certo Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Como nosso amigo Manieiro disse, é pura matemática.

Basta multiplicar a **porcentagem pelo valor.**

**Exemplo:** calcular 30% de 700.

Basta multiplicar a fração 30/100 por 700.

[image: Exemplo prático]

Agora no PL/SQL eu tenho a coluna **porcentagem** que é o valor referente a **50%** da coluna ao lado direito **titu_valo** que é corresponde a mensalidade.

Faço exatamente como explicado acima, primeiro entre parêntesis eu faço o cálculo da fração de 50 que corresponde a 50% dividido por 100 que é o denominador da porcentagem e logo depois em seguida multiplico pelo valor da mensalidade, ficando assim:

```
((50/100) * titu_valo)
```

[image: Exemplo Prático]

**Resultado:**

[image: Resultado da porcentagem]